# Center cover page (Image) vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment

So I've designed an image for the cover of my book and I want to center it vertically, I tried two things and both failed.
It's a small image that DOES NOT cover the whole page.

I tired with `vspace` first, it doesn't move the image, no matter what.

```
\vspace{3in}
\includegraphics{147.jpg}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

And also I tried with `vfill`.

```
\vfill
\includegraphics{147.jpg}
\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Do I have to insert it in a table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should have used `vspace*` instead of `vspace`
Example:

```
\vspace*{3in}
\includegraphics{147.jpg}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To make this a valid answer please add a complete, short, compilable code (called Minimal Working Example, short MWE) to your code.  See question https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/16550